# Running a Fragment containing a List

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-listfragment, listadapter

I am creating an address book application using Swipe Tabs i.e "ViewPager". When i run the application it crashes. I am getting errors i dont understand. Please can anyone kindly assist me with this? Thanks.

This is my Fragm.java Fragment class.

```
package com.rufflez.viewpagerexample;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;  
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Fragm extends Fragment{
private CursorAdapter mAdapter;
public ListView listView;
public Cursor cursor;


public static final String[] FROM = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI };
private static final int[] TO = { R.id.text_name, R.id.contact_thumbnail };

int layout = R.layout.contact_list_item;

private android.content.Context context = getActivity();
public View view;
public static Uri uri;

// columns requested from the database
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP
    };

    // this goes in the CursorLoader parameter list, it filters
    // out only those contacts who have a phone number
    private static final String SELECTION = 
            ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "='1'";

    // Empty public constructor, required by the system
    public Fragm() {}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_view,
            container, true);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list); 

    Cursor c = null; // there is no cursor yet
    int flags = 0;
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, c, FROM, TO, flags);

    return view;
}
}
```

This is my TestFragmentAdapter.java class

```
package com.rufflez.viewpagerexample;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPagerAdapter;

public class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements      IconPagerAdapter{
protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] {
    "This", "Is", "A", "Test"   
};

private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getIconResId(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment1();
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        fragment = new Fragment1();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Fragm();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new Fragment3();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new Fragment4();
        break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    String title = "";
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        title = "Fragment 1";
        break;
    case 1:
        title = "Fragment 2";
        break;
    case 2:
        title = "Fragment 3";
        break;
    case 3:
        title = "Fragment 4";
        break;
    }

    return title;
}

public void setCount(int count){
    if (count > 0 && count < 10){
        mCount = count;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

}
```

This is my Logcat error

```
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614): Process: com.rufflez.viewpagerexample, PID: 6614
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:95)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:89)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at com.rufflez.viewpagerexample.Fragm.onCreateView(Fragm.java:55)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:874)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5827)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2897)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18580)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2248)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1306)
08-31 21:42:57.956: E/AndroidRuntime(6614):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1548)
```

Comment: You're not using TestFragmentAdapter. You're using SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: Remove this line: `private android.content.Context context = getActivity();` It is invoked at construction time when the fragment is not attached to any activity. `getActivity()` only returns valid object after `onAttach` and before `onDetach`. Don't put context in a field variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `context` is null. You need to populate it after `onAttach`. One possible solution is to set it from inside your `onCreateView` method.

Here is a link to some info about the Fragment and Activity lifecycles: https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle

`getActivity()` on a Fragment will only return an Activity between `onAttach` and `onDetach`

Answer (score 0):

You get a null pointer because of the way you initialized context:

```
private Context context = getActivity();
```

The following would have worked for an activity:

```
private Context context = this;
```

But for a fragment it would be to early in the cycle, so you will need to do it after the fragment is attached.

`OnCreate()` is a good place to do this:

```
private Context context;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity();
}
```